# how show image loading while curl loads

Tags: image, curl, loading, show

I wonder how I can do that while curl form has not been sent, then I display an image loading.gif and when content is send as loading.gif remove that image.

If I can be of help thanks a lot, thanks in advance.

Comment: Even I also *wondered* without seeing any piece of code in question!

Comment: thanks for everything I have achieved by following this tutorial: http://ciclesinformatica.insjoandaustria.org/daw/anadir-loading-con-javascript-y-ajax-en-nuestro-site/